# Retrieve the information from a nested JSON value

Tags: c#, json, parsing

So I'm calling the LinkedIn API to get the profile data and it retrieves a JSON.

```
{
  "firstName": "Cristian Viorel",
  "headline": ".NET Developer",
  "location": {
    "country": {"code": "dk"},
    "name": "Northern Region, Denmark"
  },
  "pictureUrls": {
    "_total": 1,
    "values": ["https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_PXALDpO4eCHpt5z..."]
  }
}
```

I can use student.firstname, student.headline. How can I get the name of the location, or the value of the pictureUrl ?
Something like student.location.name or student.pictureUrls.values ?

Comment: Have you tried your suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy with [`Json.Net`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). You first define your model:

```
public class Country
{
    public string code { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public Country country { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class PictureUrls
{
    public int _total { get; set; }
    public List<string> values { get; set; }
}

public class JsonResult
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string headline { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public PictureUrls pictureUrls { get; set; }
}
```

Then you simply parse your Json data:

```
string json = @"{
      'firstName': 'Cristian Viorel',
      'headline': '.NET Developer',
      'location': {
        'country': {'code': 'dk'},
        'name': 'Northern Region, Denmark'
      },
      'pictureUrls': {
        '_total': 1,
        'values': ['https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_PXALDpO4eCHpt5z...']
      }
    }";

JsonResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(json);

Console.WriteLine(result.location.name);

foreach (var pictureUrl in result.pictureUrls.values)
    Console.WriteLine(pictureUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the name yes, but for picture you need a for loop or if you just want the first item student.pictureUrls.values[0] (values seems to be an array).